# Can we use alert click as selector in $().onclick(function()) ? & how?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing login and after successful login it shows alert. on click that alert, can I use it as selector for  `$().onclick(function())` ? and if how ? I want that `onclick` alert it should hide div.
The code is-

```
(function() {
    $().onclick(function()) {
        $('#log1').hide();
        $('#com').show();
    }
})();
```

Comment: If an alert showed, user should have to click ok. There is no other option. So you can hide the div just after the alert call. It will wait for the user to click the ok button.

Comment: By the way, what's the purpose of the alert, just showing the message "login successful" to the user? If yes, I think it's more user-friendly to show a "notification" instead (for example by using the jNotify plugin for jQuery).

Comment: but how should I use that click event in my code- $(selector).onclick(function()) ? What should i put instead of selector?

Comment: @user3753504 you can't handle that click event as far as i know. the code that follows `alert()` obviously assumes that the user dismissed it, otherwise it won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Anoop Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2281280/anoop-joshi) pointed out in comments, the [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert)

> prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed

So user will have to dismiss the alert first to continue using your program: hence you can write the code for hiding the `<div>` right after you call `alert()`.

If you're trying to provide the user with an option to choose whether to hide the `<div>` or not, look into [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm) or [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.prompt)

Comment: Yes you are right. I have done it with ajax its going correct but I dont know its correct way of coding or not. code is here-`(function() 
{
$.ajax({
success:function()
{
$('#log1').hide();       $('#com').show();
}
})

})();`

Comment: @Siddhesh i don't see anything wrong with that code... but i don't see any `alert()` as well...